# Nuxt Js Laravel API Unable to verify first certificate

Tags: node.js, laravel, ssl, nuxt.js

### Some Background about tech stack

We are using Vue.JS for front end and APIs are in Laravel. Frontend and backend are separate repositories. We have deployed it on Google Kubernetes Engine. We decided to move the frontend from Vue.Js to **Nuxt.js**

### Problem:

When we hit any API from Nuxt.js, it throws below error

`client.js?06a0:57 Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

The websites which are on Vue.js have never gave this error and still works fine.

### Things tried so far:

We have implemented `https` package but that results in docker container crashing in kubernetes. We have implemented new SSL certificates on our API domain by uploading SSL certificates but nothing seems to work so far.

Is it something that has to be configured from JS side of things or is it a problem with API domain SSL. Any help or comments appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with SSL certificates. It was not configured correctly on GKE. I had to create valid certificate chain my self by combining two files given by SSL.

Comment: You could have provide some information regarding your answer.

Comment: To make sure that either my SSL is configured correctly or not, I used a command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect capwell.nl:443` which returns certificate chain info and its status. If status code is not `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`. This means that SSL is not configured correctly.
As I was using GKE and custom SSL certs, I had to manually combine two ca_bundle and certificate files, then upload them in GKE. This resulted in certificate chain complete and my issue got resolved.